# Como ir para um url em django independente do caminho que estamos?

Tags: html5, django, django-templates

Eu criei um menu em um arquivo base que fica visível independente da pagina que estamos,

```
        <p> Tela de perfil <a href="perfil/">Perfil</a></p>
```

O problema e que quando estamos na mesma pagina e clicamos no mesmo link,o "Perfil" e duplicado dando um erro,

Como posso colocar para ir para pagina que esteja independente se já estou ou não nela, ou em um caminho diferente ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que o Puam Dias respondeu está correto. Lembrando apenas que para usar essa tag é necessário nomear a rota no arquivo urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^perfil/$', perfil_function, name='perfil'),
]
```

É o atributo name='perfil' que possibilita você fazer dessa forma no template:

```
<a href="{% url 'perfil' %}">Perfil</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Não é recomendável que você utilize as urls dessa forma, porque isso pode gerar erros silenciosos em sua aplicação. Se um dia você acabar mudando a sua url para 'perfil-alguma-coisa', ao acessar esse template, ele continuará sendo renderizado normalmente sem acusar o erro. Só quando tu clicar no link, é que o erro será exibido.

Tente chamar as urls com as tags do django:

```
<p>Tela de perfil <a href="{% url 'perfil' %}">Perfil</a></p>
```

ou

```
<p>Tela de perfil <a href="{% url 'namespace:perfil' %}">Perfil</a></p>
```

para caso a sua url esteja dentro de uma app com namespace.